# Portable EV chargers with "normal" US/Can 230V plugs?

Tags: electric-vehicle

I've put in my down payment for my first EV, and now have two years to buy the add-ons while it arrives (yes, two years).

My garage already has a 230V/100A pony panel, so I'm going to have a NEMA 14-50 installed and buy a good home charger.

But I will also need a portable unit, and here's the problem - all the ones I can find that even accept 230V use weird plugs like NEMA 6-20 and such. So...

1. Why don't they use 14-50 or 14-30?
2. Why bother even putting on this plug? Aside from welding shops, you're going to have to have one custom wired, so it's useless for portable use. Whereas every home I know has at least a 14-30 *somewhere*.

Does anyone know if there is any logical reason for this?

Comment: I've edited out the last question. I believe the other is answerable. The last question was a shopping question, which would have made it off-topic for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a current owner (no pun intended) of an [eMotorWerks](https://emotorwerks.com/) charging station connected to a NEMA 14-50 outlet, I can suggest that your searches may be missing a few locations.

From their web site opening page:

> Take JuiceBox along with you. All JuiceBox EV charging stations use
>   standard outlets and don’t require expensive, hard-wired
>   installations.

From the same web site, one can purchase adapters if one is in a situation which requires an [adapter](https://emotorwerks.com/store/accessories/juicebox-adapters-input-cables) in the other direction. Their adapters allow you to connect the NEMA 14-50 into dryer and general household outlets (110v only).

Our JuiceBox 40 was purchased without the wifi option and I would have liked to have the ability to monitor the usage. With a 40 amp charge level, the vehicle charges faster than the computer forecasts, leaving us in a guessing game with how long it takes.

[image: juice box evse image]

The lead from the outlet to the EVSE is rather short, but should not pose a problem with portability.

[image: evse image 2]

I think my lead might be a bit longer, as the unit is a year old and not as prettified as this newer model. It's just an ordinary weather sealed brushed aluminum box with wires, no lights, bells or whistles. I had inquired about a trade-in for the wifi version but the exchange rate convinced me otherwise.

Most (all?) US campgrounds which provide electrical service will have NEMA 14-50 outlets, making charging convenient in certain parts of this country.